# how do i split one vector element into two?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have the following code:

```
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt") ##creates list of all txt. files in folder

file_list

o<- file_list[order(as.numeric(gsub(".+_(\\d+)\\.txt$", "\\1", file_list)))]## orders list in numerical order by ending 

r <- sapply(o, FUN = function(x){

  df = read.table(x, skip=1) ##x is the file name from list 

  mean(df$V4)

}) ###takes mean of selected column from entire list and produces below output
```

this provides the following output:

```
172010_001_120VC_0.1_1100.txt   3.817672e-07
172010_001_120VC_0.1_1080.txt   3.893099e-07 
172010_001_120VC_0.1_1090.txt   4.386539e-07
```

How do I turn the output into a vector/data frame were x= the last digits of txt file label (1100, 1080, 1090, etc, and y = the numerical value (3.817672e-07, 3.893099e-07, 4.386539e-07 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the length of all the vector elements in this case is same, you can use `substr()` function (which is in `base` package only. ) by providing positions of characters directly.

**Creating Output given in Question**

```
vec <- c("172010_001_120VC_0.1_1100.txt   3.817672e-07","172010_001_120VC_0.1_1080.txt   3.893099e-07","172010_001_120VC_0.1_1090.txt   4.386539e-07")
```

**Printed Output given in Question**

```
vec
# [1] "172010_001_120VC_0.1_1100.txt   3.817672e-07"
# [2] "172010_001_120VC_0.1_1080.txt   3.893099e-07"
# [3] "172010_001_120VC_0.1_1090.txt   4.386539e-07"
```

**Required Result using `substr()` function**

```
df <- data.frame(x = substr(vec, 22, 25), y = substr(vec, 33, 44))
df
#      x            y
# 1 1100 3.817672e-07
# 2 1080 3.893099e-07
# 3 1090 4.386539e-07
```

Comment: The output you provided is what I'm after but there are approximately 100 files , is there anyway to go about your approach without manually entering all of them? the length for all 100 are the same

Comment: You mean 100 files in the output of your code right?

Comment: The `vec` should have the names of those files and numerical value as a single string..so this code will work easily.  Store your output in a vector like I have done. As you you said those are output from the above code..so just store it in an object, no need to create vector manually. use that object in this code to split its each element. Let me know if any problem. In your case, object `r` has all the file names and numerical value, use `r` object in the above script instead of `vec`.